# Return Boolean value from Neo4j cypher query

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I would like to check whether a node exists using its name (instead of its ID). The Cypher query looks like :

```
MATCH (c:Jaguar{name:"JLR 2.5Ltr"})-[:REPRESENTED_BY]->(v) RETURN c IS NOT NULL
```

However, Using neo4j shell/web console, the result returned is of type String. The same fails in spring-data-neo4j with error :

```
Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public abstract boolean xxx.yyy.repository.SomeRepository.checkIfDatasetExists(java.lang.String)
```

Has somebody come across any work around for this

Answer (score 10):

The answer provided by Supamiu will not work unfortunately, you need to hack this by returning a count expression :

```
MATCH (c:Jaguar{name:"JLR 2.5Ltr"})-[:REPRESENTED_BY]->(v) 
RETURN count(c) > 0 as c
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use CASE to check if your node is null or not, and return the value you need :

```
MATCH (c:Jaguar{name:"JLR 2.5Ltr"})-[:REPRESENTED_BY]->(v)
RETURN CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN false ELSE true END as c
```

More informations can be found on [Neo4j's Documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-expressions.html#syntax-simple-case)

Comment: Thanks for the query. I tried testing it and it works fine. When I tried the same one for the scenario where node does n't exists it returns `(no changes, no records)` instead of false

Answer (score 2):

It is supported now in the latest version, you can use the predicate functions:

`exists()`

```
MATCH   (c:Jaguar{name:"JLR 2.5Ltr"})
RETURN  exists((c)-[:REPRESENTED_BY]->(v)) // returns boolean
```

[Docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/#functions-exists)